# From NASM to MASM

Tags: assembly, syntax, nasm, masm

I've check windows documentation on masm, and also searched for some equivalences between both syntax, but didn't find anything.
I tried to change this code from nasm to masm:

NASM version:

```
section .data
    text1 db "What is your name?"
    text2 db "Hello, "

section .bss
    name resb 16

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    call _printText1
    call _getName
    call _printText2
    call _printName
    
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
    ret

_getName:
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret

_printText1:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text1
    mov rdx, 19
    syscall
    ret

_printText2:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text2
    mov rdx, 7
    syscall
    ret

_printName:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret
```

MASM version:

```
.data
    text1 db "What is your name?"
    text2 db "Hello, "

.data?
    name resb 16

.code
main proc
    call _printText1
    call _getName
    call _printText2
    call _printName
    
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
    ret

_getName:
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret

_printText1:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text1
    mov rdx, 19
    syscall
    ret

_printText2:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text2
    mov rdx, 7
    syscall
    ret

_printName:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret

main endp
end
```

What I don't understand is: what's the MASM version of resb?
From what I found .data? is the same as .bss, hence I changed it.
Also what can I use instead of global _start?
Is there any documentation that provides an understanding of both syntax equivalences?

Comment: Is this just an exercise in learning syntax?  Those Linux system-call numbers only work on Linux, and I don't think MASM can make Linux executables. This won't run on Windows even if you do assemble the same data and machine code into the right sections using MASM.  If you still want to continue instead of finding a MASM example that reserves space for an array and declares a symbol that's visible to the linker, you could try looking at MSVC output for a .c with a global array and function.

Comment: I can't find a canonical duplicate that explains reserving space in the BSS in MASM with `db 16 dup(?)`  This search (https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bmasm%5d%20code%3a%22dup%22%20code%3a%22(%3f)%22) finds 99 [masm] posts with `dup` and `(?)` in them, but they mention or use it without fully explaining it, or at least not being about it.  Maybe there's a canonical with a [tasm] tag or something, or maybe people use use `size dup(0)` in .bss in code designed to run under Windows (where the BSS does get zeroed.)  Many explaining `dup('$')` or other non-? things, though.